# Make a UIView with a blurred view as borderColor

Tags: ios, arrays, uiview

I need to create a `UIView` with a blurred view as `borderColor`.

How can I get that to work?

I have attached a sample image as an example of my requirement.[image]

Thanks

Comment: The best way is to do it is using layers.

Comment: you can add it as subview to a blurred view, and update the blurred view size to match the subview with some offset.

Comment: just give a shadows to your UIView

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the border of a UITextField has a fading property, or anything similar. However, with a bit of work, you can accomplish what you need:

1) Download/acquire a background image that has the border you want. It can be rectangular. Add it to your project.
2) In IB, set the BorderStyle of you TextView to None, the BackgroundImage to the image you added, and add an outlet to your UIViewController class.
3) Add the following code to your viewDidLoad. Replace  with the name of your IBOutlet:

```
<textField>.layer.cornerRadius =5.0
```

This should give you a UITextField with rounded corners and your background image. You may have to play around with your image and the cornerRadius values to get exactly what you want, but the code should work.

Comment: Actually, thats a UIView with a TextField and UIImageView as subViews. I Just want the blur around the UIView

Answer (score 0):

Use my code its work perfectly. Textviewview is my One UIView and inside it one textfield and one UIImageview i use.

```
Textviewview.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
Textviewview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
Textviewview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)
Textviewview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
Textviewview.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
```

[image]